# Search returns "Nothing Found" on a sub directory

Tags: multisite, search, mysql

I've created a multisite using subdirectories. The search function, both in backend and frontend, only works on the main site. If I try and do a search in a subdirectory it returns with "Nothing Found" even though I know the page/post exists.

In my debug.log I see this:

```
[15-Nov-2018 17:40:18 UTC] WordPress database error Unknown column 'wp_posts.post_title' in 'where clause' for query SELECT   wp_2_posts.ID, wp_2_posts.post_parent FROM wp_2_posts  WHERE 1=1 
          AND (
            (wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%home%')
            OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%home%')
            OR EXISTS (
              SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta
                  WHERE post_id = wp_posts.ID
                    AND ( (meta_key LIKE '%title%' AND meta_value LIKE '%home%')  OR (meta_key LIKE '%sub_title%' AND meta_value LIKE '%home%')  OR (meta_key LIKE '%excerpt_short%' AND meta_value LIKE '%home%')  OR (meta_key LIKE '%excerpt_long%' AND meta_value LIKE '%home%')  OR (meta_key LIKE '%xyz%' AND meta_value LIKE '%home%')  OR (meta_key LIKE '%myACF%' AND meta_value LIKE '%home%') )
            )
            OR EXISTS (
              SELECT * FROM wp_comments
              WHERE comment_post_ID = wp_posts.ID
                AND comment_content LIKE '%home%'
            )
            OR EXISTS (
              SELECT * FROM wp_terms
              INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy
                ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id
              INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships
                ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
              WHERE (
                taxonomy = 'post_tag'
                    OR taxonomy = 'category'
                    OR taxonomy = 'myCustomTax'
                )
                AND object_id = wp_posts.ID
                AND wp_terms.name LIKE '%home%'
            )
        ) AND wp_2_posts.post_type = 'page' AND (wp_2_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_2_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR wp_2_posts.post_status = 'future' OR wp_2_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR wp_2_posts.post_status = 'pending' OR wp_2_posts.post_status = 'private')  ORDER BY wp_2_posts.menu_order ASC, wp_2_posts.post_title ASC  made by WP_Posts_List_Table->prepare_items, wp_edit_posts_query, wp, WP->main, WP->query_posts, WP_Query->query, WP_Query->get_posts, W3TC\DbCache_Wpdb->query, W3TC\DbCache_WpdbInjection_QueryCaching->query, W3TC\_CallUnderlying->query, W3TC\DbCache_Wpdb->query, W3TC\DbCache_WpdbInjection->query, W3TC\DbCache_Wpdb->default_query
[15-Nov-2018 17:40:18 UTC] WordPress database error Unknown column 'wp_posts.post_title' in 'where clause' for query SELECT   wp_2_posts.ID, wp_2_posts.post_parent FROM wp_2_posts  WHERE 1=1 
          AND (
            (wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%home%')
            OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%home%')
            OR EXISTS (
              SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta
                  WHERE post_id = wp_posts.ID
                    AND ( (meta_key LIKE '%title%' AND meta_value LIKE '%home%')  OR (meta_key LIKE '%sub_title%' AND meta_value LIKE '%home%')  OR (meta_key LIKE '%excerpt_short%' AND meta_value LIKE '%home%')  OR (meta_key LIKE '%excerpt_long%' AND meta_value LIKE '%home%')  OR (meta_key LIKE '%xyz%' AND meta_value LIKE '%home%')  OR (meta_key LIKE '%myACF%' AND meta_value LIKE '%home%') )
            )
            OR EXISTS (
              SELECT * FROM wp_comments
              WHERE comment_post_ID = wp_posts.ID
                AND comment_content LIKE '%home%'
            )
            OR EXISTS (
              SELECT * FROM wp_terms
              INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy
                ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id
              INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships
                ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
              WHERE (
                taxonomy = 'post_tag'
                    OR taxonomy = 'category'
                    OR taxonomy = 'myCustomTax'
                )
                AND object_id = wp_posts.ID
                AND wp_terms.name LIKE '%home%'
            )
        ) AND wp_2_posts.post_type = 'page' AND (wp_2_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_2_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR wp_2_posts.post_status = 'future' OR wp_2_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR wp_2_posts.post_status = 'pending' OR wp_2_posts.post_status = 'private')  ORDER BY wp_2_posts.menu_order ASC, wp_2_posts.post_title ASC  made by WP_List_Table->display, WP_List_Table->display_tablenav, WP_Posts_List_Table->extra_tablenav, do_action('manage_posts_extra_tablenav'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WPSEO_Link_Columns->count_objects, WPSEO_Link_Columns->set_count_objects, WP_Query->get_posts, W3TC\DbCache_Wpdb->query, W3TC\DbCache_WpdbInjection_QueryCaching->query, W3TC\_CallUnderlying->query, W3TC\DbCache_Wpdb->query, W3TC\DbCache_WpdbInjection->query, W3TC\DbCache_Wpdb->default_query
```

I'm not seeing errors pop up anywhere else on the site

Search form code:

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" class="search-form">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 search-container">
        <input type="search" id="input-s" name="s" placeholder="Search For:" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 submit-btn-container">
        <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: try turning off database / object cache in w3tc and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @majick that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well this is not exactly to do with subdirectories as such, but there is something mixing up the queries between the subsites...

As you can see the error is saying `wp_posts.post_title` is not found - because the table selected is actually `FROM wp_2_posts`... showing the different table prefixes for site 1 `wp_` and site 2 `wp_2_`... so one will not be found within the other.

It could be the form action destination perhaps, try replacing `home_url('/')` with `get_site_url(null, '/')`, and hopefully the search form will post to the correct site. Not sure if that will fix it though.

Otherwise it could be a plugin that doesn't support multisite messing up the search query somehow by not using `$wpdb->prefix` instead of `wp_` when creating the query. If that's the case try disabling any plugins that might be doing that...

Comment: Neither of those solutions seems to work. I've tried to disable all of the plugins and reactivating one by one but search still wont work. I dont get any new errors in the debug.log. I changed the form action destination but that doesn't work either :/